# Drag-and-drop Javascript if Statement Problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, game-development

I'm currently developing a javascript game utilising the drag and drop feature of HTML.
What I'm trying to do here is to allow randomly generated fruit images to be draggable and droppable onto the jelly image. Then if the dragged image is matching condition set (which is when number image array index == x, and fruit image index is == y), allow it to drop.
And in order to declare this if statement, I'm grabbing the value from background image. (If the background image of number is x, and background image of fruit is y)
My code was executing fine until I tried to set a condition to it. And logically I don't understand why it won't work when there's an if statement to it, it even won't display images.

Edit: tried using === instead of =, still not responsive

Edit: after removing the semicolon as in comment, the rest of the code executes fine. However drag and drop won't respond.

Edit: declared variables of image urls instead of using urls directly in on drop function. Drag and drop still doesn't work.

```js
var myNumber = new Array(9);

myNumber[0] = '1.png';
myNumber[1] = '2.png';
myNumber[2] = '3.png';
myNumber[3] = '4.png';
myNumber[4] = '5.png';
myNumber[5] = '6.png';
myNumber[6] = '7.png';
myNumber[7] = '8.png';
myNumber[8] = '9.png';

var numberImage1 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[0] + ")";
var numberImage2 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[1] + ")";
var numberImage3 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[2] + ")";
var numberImage4 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[3] + ")";
var numberImage5 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[4] + ")";
var numberImage6 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[5] + ")";
var numberImage7 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[6] + ")";
var numberImage8 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[7] + ")";
var numberImage9 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[8] + ")";



var fruitCloudOne = new Array(15);

fruitCloudOne[0] = '3apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[1] = '3banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[2] = '3blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[3] = '3plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[4] = '3strawberry.png';

fruitCloudOne[5] = '5apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[6] = '5banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[7] = '5blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[8] = '5plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[9] = '5strawberry.png';

fruitCloudOne[10] = '8apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[11] = '8banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[12] = '8blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[13] = '8plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[14] = '8strawberry.png';

var apple3 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[0] + ")";
var banana3 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[1] + ")";
var blueberry3 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[2] + ")";
var plum3 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[3] + ")";
var strawberry3 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[4] + ")";

var apple5 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[5] + ")";
var banana5 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[6] + ")";
var blueberry5 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[7] + ")";
var plum5 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[8] + ")";
var strawberry5 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[9] + ")";

var apple8 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[10] + ")";
var banana8 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[11] + ")";
var blueberry8 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[12] + ")";
var plum8 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[13] + ")";
var strawberry8 = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[14] + ")";



var fruitCloudTwo = new Array(15);

fruitCloudTwo[0] = '1apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[1] = '1banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[2] = '1blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[3] = '1plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[4] = '1strawberry.png';

fruitCloudTwo[5] = '2apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[6] = '2banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[7] = '2blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[8] = '2plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[9] = '2strawberry.png';

fruitCloudTwo[10] = '4apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[11] = '4banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[12] = '4blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[13] = '4plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[14] = '4strawberry.png';

var apple1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[0] + ")";
var banana1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[1] + ")";
var blueberry1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[2] + ")";
var plum1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[3] + ")";
var strawberry1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[4] + ")";

var apple2 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[5] + ")";
var banana2 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[6] + ")";
var blueberry2 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[7] + ")";
var plum2 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[8] + ")";
var strawberry2 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[9] + ")";

var apple4 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[10] + ")";
var banana4 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[11] + ")";
var blueberry4 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[12] + ")";
var plum4 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[13] + ")";
var strawberry4 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[14] + ")";



var fruitCloudThree = new Array(15);

fruitCloudThree[0] = '6apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[1] = '6banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[2] = '6blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[3] = '6plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[4] = '6strawberry.png';

fruitCloudThree[5] = '7apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[6] = '7banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[7] = '7blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[8] = '7plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[9] = '7strawberry.png';

fruitCloudThree[10] = '9apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[11] = '9banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[12] = '9blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[13] = '9plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[14] = '9strawberry.png';

var apple6 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[0] + ")";
var banana6 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[1] + ")";
var blueberry6 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[2] + ")";
var plum6 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[3] + ")";
var strawberry6 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[4] + ")";

var apple7 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[5] + ")";
var banana7 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[6] + ")";
var blueberry7 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[7] + ")";
var plum7 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[8] + ")";
var strawberry7 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[9] + ")";

var apple9 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[10] + ")";
var banana9 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[11] + ")";
var blueberry9 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[12] + ")";
var plum9 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[13] + ")";
var strawberry9 = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[14] + ")";



//random generation of number and fruits & display
var numberAddress = 'Assets/Numbers/';

var fruit1Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud1/';
var randFruit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudOne.length));
var randFruit1Image = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[randFruit1] + ")";

var fruit2Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud2/';
var randFruit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudTwo.length));
var randFruit2Image = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[randFruit2] + ")";

var fruit3Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud3/';
var randFruit3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudThree.length));
var randFruit3Image = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[randFruit3] + ")";

//refresh fruit images
function refreshFruits() {
    var fruit1Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud1/';
    var randFruit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudOne.length));
    var randFruit1Image = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[randFruit1] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit1").style.backgroundImage = randFruit1Image;

    var fruit2Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud2/';
    var randFruit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudTwo.length));
    var randFruit2Image = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[randFruit2] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = randFruit2Image;

    var fruit3Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud3/';
    var randFruit3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudThree.length));
    var randFruit3Image = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[randFruit3] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit3").style.backgroundImage = randFruit3Image;
}

//display number and three fruit images
function startGame() {
    var numberImage1 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[0] + ")";
    document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage = numberImage1;

    document.getElementById("fruit1").style.backgroundImage = randFruit1Image;

    document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = randFruit2Image;

    document.getElementById("fruit3").style.backgroundImage = randFruit3Image;
}


    
function dragOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("fruit", ev.target.id);
}

function onDrop(ev) {
    var numberImage1 =  "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[0] + ")";
    var apple1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[0] + ")";
    var banana1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[1] + ")";
    var blueberry1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[2] + ")";
    var plum1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[3] + ")";
    var strawberry1 = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[4] + ")";
    
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == numberImage1 && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == apple1) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == numberImage1 && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == banana1) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == numberImage1 && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == blueberry1) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == numberImage1 && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == plum1) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == numberImage1 && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == strawberry1) {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/Background_cloudPosition.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: -10;
}

#startGame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}

#refreshFruits {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#number {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    left: 450px;
    bottom: 415px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 460px;
    left: 135px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 185px;
    left: 110px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruit1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#fruit2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#fruit3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#jelly {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/JellyMonster/JellyMonsterDefault.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 260px;
    height: 190px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 390px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>This is an experiment.</title>
    
</head>
    
<body>
<!--- 
<a id="download" href="index.html"></a>--->
    
<button id="startGame" onclick="startGame()"></button>
<button id="refreshFruits" onclick="refreshFruits()"></button>

<div id="number"></div>
    
<div id="jelly" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="dragOver(event)"></div>

<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud1">
    <div id="fruit1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)"></div>
</div>

<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud2">
    <div id="fruit2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)"></div>
</div>
    
<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud3">
    <div id="fruit3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)"></div>
</div>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use document to store data, use a JS feature, like a variable, object or array.

Comment: I guess the part `document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[fruitTwoIndex] + ")";` is missing a `=` for the comparisson. Also you might need to use `===` to ensure you're comparing the right types.

Comment: @Teemu Which part are you referring to?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Yeah I realised that right after posting as well haha
But the whole thing still doesn't work. When I comment out that if statement, everything executes fine. But with that if statement, even displaying images won't work.

Comment: If you find and fix these issues in your code, please also update the question. Most of the time people will stop looking for deeper problems when they find an obvious one (just as I did). You will get a better answer a lot faster.

Comment: @Angela Any part detecting anything from the DOM, and then comparing it something else. The page is for showing your data, not the data itself.

Comment: @Angela remove the ";" after the if statement and see if this helps your issue. The semi-colon doesn't belong at the end of the if statement. 
Example: `if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[numberIndex] + ")" && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[fruitTwoIndex] + ")") {//rest of the code here}`

Comment: @HeroZero Thank you, it helped with the rest of the code to execute. However the drag and drop is still not responsive.

Comment: @Angela Use** https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ** its easy

Comment: @Teemu I've tried declaring variables for the image url outputs. The rest is fine but the drop function still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The problem is, that you're trying to save the state of the game in the HTML elements and CSS. Use a JS object instead. Ex. checking an URL of a background can give you what ever content depending on the environment, it's not reliable data, but when you add a robust value to an object, and then check that value, you can rely on your comparison will get correct data to compare. In other words: model your game in JS, and only show the results of the changes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So got this code to work.

I changed the if statement a bit, turns out there was a type error in it. I've added some console log statements so you can see the output. Drag and drop is working when the conditions match, because of the random generation, I've had to refresh the screen a lot sometimes while testing to get the drop. The concept is cool and out of the box, but may need some refactoring to help minimize your code and allow for readability. When looking at the example you will need to show it in full screen because it squshes everything together here...

Hope this helps

```js
var myNumber = new Array(9);

myNumber[0] = '1.png';
myNumber[1] = '2.png';
myNumber[2] = '3.png';
myNumber[3] = '4.png';
myNumber[4] = '5.png';
myNumber[5] = '6.png';
myNumber[6] = '7.png';
myNumber[7] = '8.png';
myNumber[8] = '9.png';


var fruitCloudOne = new Array(15);

fruitCloudOne[0] = '3apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[1] = '3banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[2] = '3blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[3] = '3plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[4] = '3strawberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[5] = '5apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[6] = '5banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[7] = '5blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[8] = '5plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[9] = '5strawberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[10] = '8apple.png';
fruitCloudOne[11] = '8banana.png';
fruitCloudOne[12] = '8blueberry.png';
fruitCloudOne[13] = '8plum.png';
fruitCloudOne[14] = '8strawberry.png';


var fruitCloudTwo = new Array(15);

fruitCloudTwo[0] = '1apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[1] = '1banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[2] = '1blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[3] = '1plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[4] = '1strawberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[5] = '2apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[6] = '2banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[7] = '2blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[8] = '2plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[9] = '2strawberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[10] = '4apple.png';
fruitCloudTwo[11] = '4banana.png';
fruitCloudTwo[12] = '4blueberry.png';
fruitCloudTwo[13] = '4plum.png';
fruitCloudTwo[14] = '4strawberry.png';


var fruitCloudThree = new Array(15);

fruitCloudThree[0] = '6apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[1] = '6banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[2] = '6blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[3] = '6plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[4] = '6strawberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[5] = '7apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[6] = '7banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[7] = '7blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[8] = '7plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[9] = '7strawberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[10] = '9apple.png';
fruitCloudThree[11] = '9banana.png';
fruitCloudThree[12] = '9blueberry.png';
fruitCloudThree[13] = '9plum.png';
fruitCloudThree[14] = '9strawberry.png';


//random generation of number and fruits & display

var numberAddress = 'Assets/Numbers/';
var numberIndex = 0;
var fruitOneIndex = 0;
var fruitTwoIndex = 0;
var fruitThreeIndex = 0;

var fruit1Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud1/';
var randFruit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudOne.length));

var fruit2Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud2/';
var randFruit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudTwo.length));

var fruit3Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud3/';
var randFruit3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudThree.length));


function refreshFruits() {
  var fruit1Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud1/';
  var randFruit1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudOne.length));
  document.getElementById("fruit1").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[randFruit1] + ")";

  var fruit2Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud2/';
  var randFruit2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudTwo.length));
  document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[randFruit2] + ")";

  var fruit3Address = 'Assets/FruitCloud3/';
  var randFruit3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fruitCloudThree.length));
  document.getElementById("fruit3").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[randFruit3] + ")";
}


function startGame() {
  document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[numberIndex] + ")";

  document.getElementById("fruit1").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[randFruit1] + ")";

  document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[randFruit2] + ")";

  document.getElementById("fruit3").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[randFruit3] + ")";
}



function dragOver(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("fruit", ev.target.id);
}

//PROBLEM ARISE HERE
function onDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage);
  console.log("What we are expecting to see " + document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage );
  console.log("What we are getting " + 'url("' + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[fruitTwoIndex] + '")');
  
  if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == 'url("' + numberAddress + myNumber[numberIndex] +'")' && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == 'url("' + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[fruitTwoIndex] + '")') {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log('finally got one');
  }else{
    console.log('Try Again');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  #background {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/Background_cloudPosition.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: -10;
  }
  
  #number {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    left: 450px;
    bottom: 415px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  
  #fruitCloud1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 460px;
    left: 135px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  
  #fruitCloud2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  
  #fruitCloud3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 185px;
    left: 110px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  
  #fruit1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rosybrown;
  }
  
  #fruit2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  
  #fruit3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  
  #jelly {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/JellyMonster/JellyMonsterDefault.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 260px;
    height: 190px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 390px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  #startGame {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  #refreshFruits {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <title>This is an experiment.</title>

</head>

<body>

  <button id="startGame" onclick="startGame()">Start</button>
  <button id="refreshFruits" onclick="refreshFruits()">Refresh</button>

  <div id="number"></div>

  <div id="jelly" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="dragOver(event)">Jelly</div>

  <div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud1">
    <div id="fruit1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Fruit 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud2">
    <div id="fruit2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Fruit 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud3">
    <div id="fruit3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Fruit 3</div>
  </div>

</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but this worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also found a more ideal way to test this.
Instead of testing background images, I used the if condition to test whether the dragged data's id is matching the id of the div wanted.
To do this, I had to put all images in one array and alter random generation of the fruit images to make sure I will always get the image I want for each stage.